# Reduction on array in FORTRAN

Tags: fortran

I'm trying to parallelize a module in my FORTRAN code using OpenMP and I'm running into some issues with threads overwriting updated values in the array. Obviously my first instinct was to do a reduction, but I'm not really sure how to go about it in this context, as I've only done it in a simple x = x + update kind of situation, where-as this is similar, but does so in a normally out-of-order fashion, and also in an array.

```
subroutine chargeInterp(q,x,xmin,xmax,dg,np,ng)
real(kind = 8) :: charge, dg, xmin, weight, xmax,wp
integer :: g1,g2,g1temp,g2temp,i,np,ng
real(kind = 8), dimension(np) :: q,x


!$OMP PARALLEL DO PRIVATE(g1,g2) REDUCTION(+:q)
do i=1,np

g1 = floor((x(i)-xmin)/dg)
g2 = g1 + 1
wp=((x(i)-xmin)/dg-g1)
weight=1-wp
q(g1+1) = q(g1+1) - weight 
q(g2+1) = q(g2+1) - wp      
enddo   
!$OMP END PARALLEL DO
```

Just to give a rundown of what it's doing, essentially it's taking the position of a particle and weighting its charge onto adjacent grid points on the mesh.

Thanks for the help!

P.S. The omp statements wrapped around the loop don't work. Just throwing that one out there. Have also tried !$OMP ATOMIC before updating q. Compiles and runs, but my results don't match my un-parallelized results, so it's a no-go.

Comment: Barely looked but at the very least i, wp and weight ought to be private as well. Oh, and it's spelt Fortran, lower case - has been officially for ~quarter of a century now.

Comment: Thanks! Also, yeah, force of habit. My department happens to be full of people over the age of 60, so, old habits are hard to break, and easy to communicate apparently.

Comment: Just tried adding those as private...my results file is empty, so the code seemed to break there. Unfortunately my code uses HDF5, and I don't have access to stdout so I can't see exactly what errors it throws barring a segfault or something, but I can tell it didn't run by not having results, hah.

Comment: 1) post the single threaded version of your code (I do not know what you actually want to achieve); 2) do it without a reduction (i.e. do the reduction operation yourself); 3) does the code compile? The OpenMP tutorial tells me that the reduction variable has to be a scalar (yours is an array). This might have changed but then it may not behave the way you would normally expect. 4) "threads overwriting updated values in the array" - which array, `q`? But since `q` is a reduction each thread has a private copy of it and they cannot override each other's values.

Comment: 5) If your compiler accepts `q` as an array and it is what it really should be then perhaps the problem is that you do not initialize `q`. As I understand your code the threads will not write in all elements of `q` thus each thread's copy will contain garbage that will be added to other threads' calculations (assuming the reduction operation on an array works as you would expect).